# Solve for $x$ in $x^3 + (-3)^4 = 17$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> We have $$x^3  + (-3)^4 = 17$$

Math beginner here! How do you simplify and get $x$? My first time posting so feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Compute $(-3)^4$. Subtract it from both sides. Take cube roots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, first thing to do is to simplify the $(-3)^4 = -3 \cdot -3 \cdot -3 \cdot -3 = 81$. Then, you get $$x^3 + 81 = 17.$$ Subtract $81$ from both sides to get $$x^3 = -64$$ Now take the cube root of both sides to get $$x = \sqrt[3]{-64} = -4$$

Answer (score 3):

$$x^{ 3 }+\left( -3 \right) ^{ 4 }=17\\ { x }^{ 3 }+81=17\\ { x }^{ 3 }=17-81=-64\\ x=\sqrt [ 3 ]{ -64 } =-4$$

Comment: Actually there are three roots of the form $4e^{\frac{\pi + 2 \pi k}{3}}$

Comment: @Aleksandar Someone who doesn't know how to solve this equation probably doesn't know what complex roots are...

Comment: @avid19 That is true.

Comment: @Aleksandar, shouldn't there be an $i$ in the power?

Comment: @ZainPatel Yes, I forgot that. However I cannot edit my comment because it has been 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cubic equation, so there must be three solutions (with possibly two redundant solutions).

$x^3 = -64$ has the solutions:

$x = \{ -4, 4 (-1)^{1/3}, 4 (-1)^{2/3} \}$.

For instance $(4 (-1)^{1/3})^3 = 4^3 ((-1)^{1/3})^3 = 64 (-1) = -64$.

Comment: The cubic is trivially injective, hence the equation has only one solution.

Comment: @ZainPatel Simply false, as Aleksandar correctly pointed out.

Comment: I was under the impression that the context in which the question was posed quite obviously exhibited that we were working in the Real field. My apologies for not realising that the OP was actually asking for all complex roots!